# Executing Python Scripts in Android

Tags: python, android, scripting

This [link](http://perlbuzz.com/2009/08/perl-coming-to-android-phones.html) says that Android support Python, Lua and BeanShell Scripts, subsequently for Perl too. If it is so, is it possible for developers to write python scripts and call them in their standard Java based android applications?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I remember reading about this awhile back as well.
It's not on the android [dev site](http://developer.android.com/index.html).

It's a separate project, [android-scripting](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/).

Python API:

[API Reference](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/ApiReference)

[SL4A API Help](http://www.mithril.com.au/android/doc/)

Comment: ASE rocks.  Made me like my android phone a whole bunch more than I already did.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have read somewhere that ASE with Python was a huge library ( several Mo), and so was completely unpractical for a public application.
But you can still use it for development...